# XIRR Formulae For each investment

Tags: excel, excel-formula, irr, xirr, vba

I am trying to apply an XIRR Formulae so that the percentage of each investment is calculated  separately.  I attempted an IF formulea  an was not successful.  I need to amend the below formulae. This will be useful as i am trying to apply it to 200 invesmtents plus.

```
=XIRR(C2:C17,B2:B17)
```

Below is the data.
[image]

Below is the result i am trying to get.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems of your data setup.  Here is how the IRR works (http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/022615/what-formula-calculating-internal-rate-return-irr-excel.asp).  Without your data, here is how you can make this to work for matching different investments.

See the attached image below and assume you are entering the formula from `cell F2` and here you go:

```
=XIRR(OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$17,0),0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$17,E2)),OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$17,0),0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$17,E2)))
```

Please note this is an array formula (need to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together)).

[image]

What I did is to use `OFFSET` to find the pertaining ranges for dates and values of each investment.  And here I have also showed you the results for a valid data inputs.  Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

pivottable can do it easily.It's not good for U?

Comment: I want it in this format , cause it will be feeding into another sheet thanks